# Using Outlook 2016 with CalDAV and CardDAV

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2016, caldav

Is it possible with to sync Outlook 2016 with CalDAV and CardDAV servers? I want to use Google Calendar and Google Contacts as well as OwnCloud. So far I'm afraid there is no "vanilla" way to sync contacts or calendar events (in both directions) without third-party plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sync CalDAV and CardDAV servers you will probably the free Outlook CalDav Synchronizer downloadable at the link below:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/outlookcaldavsynchronizer/

Comment: probably need this software and what else? Have you used, can you confirm it 100% works, and so on...

Comment: used it. Lots of issues. For example it duplicates my events for Yandex CalDAV and sends double notifications to my contacts. Dislike.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [EVO Collaborator for Outlook](http://www.evomailserver.com/google-calendar-sync-outlook.php) (paid).
I have personally confirmed that it works pretty well with Google and OwnCloud. (or NextCloud)

Comment: Can you read [how do I recommend software in my answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) and perhaps expand your answer a bit? At present it seems a bit promotional, though that may not be what you intended :)